# How do I correct a setuptools version error with Tensorflow-gpu when I run pip?

Tags: tensorflow, pip

Set up: Windows 10 Anaconda Cuda Cudann GPU set up....
When I run PIP I get this error message in RED. Does that mean my package does not install? Should I fix this? If so how? most of the pip commands I have seen show upgrade as an option, but not downgrade?

thanks

```
tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0 has requirement setuptools<=39.1.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.2.0 which is incompatible.
```

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\johnc>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 859kB/s
tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0 has requirement setuptools<=39.1.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.2.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools==39.1.0`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could use "upgrade" for a "downgrade"  ;-)  thanks